# How suppress Send/Receive Progress dialog on program exit in Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I've configured Outlook 2013 to do a send/receive when exiting, and I've checked "Don't show this dialog box during Send/Receive", but this dialog box still pops up:

[image: Dialog box]

How can I prevent this dialog from appearing? Note that it appears only when Outlook exits. Using F9 to force a full send/receive doesn't pop up the dialog.

Comment: I imagine this shows because Outlook is unable to honor your request to close until these tasks are completed. It's a bit different than receiving a pop up every time Outlook sends and receives. In this case you are being informed why Outlook has not closed.

Comment: When you hit F9, send/receive status information is displayed at the bottom of the Outlook window. The same thing could be done on closing. Regardless, checking "Don't show this dialog box during Send/Receive" seems pretty unambiguous in intent on the user's part.